# central limit theorem in term of entropy

Tags: central-limit-theorem, entropy

The usual central theorem uses iid samples.

Are there a generalizing theorem to non-iid samples, using the conditional entropy of each sample given previous ones ?

Comment: Not a duplicate, but very related:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/210669/a-dynamical-systems-view-of-the-central-limit-theorem

Comment: Yes, Liapounov’s theorem, Lindeberg-Feller theorem. Also have a look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/91768/does-the-central-limit-theorem-only-work-for-iid-random-variables